# How to convert int array into int

Tags: java, arrays, int

Currently i started reading a book about alogirthms so I'm now trying some very simple algorithms to get comfortable with converting and so on.. In this small class I want to enable a school adding function with carry.

How can i convert the resulting Int Array into an int? I do not know how to convert them adequate..

The current result is [7, 8, 3, 7, 9, 0, 5, 6] and I want to concat the numbers into one Integer of (78379056). Which possibilities do I have?

```
public class Addition {

    public int[] addiere(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int res = 0;
        int[] c = new int[a.length];
        for(int i = a.length-1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
            res = a[i]+b[i];
            if(res>=10) {
                c[i] = oneValue(res);
                a[i-1]+=1;
            } else c[i]=res;
            System.out.println("a -- "+a[i]+"  b -- "+b[i]+"  c -- "+c[i]);
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int oneValue(int t) {
        String res;
        int val;
        res=Integer.toString(t);

        res = res.substring(res.length()-1);
        val = Integer.parseInt(res);

        return val;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {3,4,6,8,9,1,2,4};
        int[] b = {4,2,5,7,8,9,3,2};

        Addition add = new Addition();
        int[] result;

        //returns an array of Integers
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(add.addiere(a, b)));

        result = add.addiere(a, b);

        //HERE should be a method to convert the result ( Array of Integers ) just into a normal integer
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add a complete problem statement to your question.  What is this method supposed to be doing?  What is the sample input and output?

Comment: Does the length of both the array same? What happens if input is `{9}, {9}`? Can array have 2 digit or 3 digit number?

Comment: @SMA I firstly just looking for the base case in which the parsed in numbers are Integers from 0 to 9. Extension maybe come later. But what I'm looking forward is the `{9}, {9}` case. Do you have any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 3):

Given the array

```
int arr[] = { 7, 8, 3, 7, 9, 0, 5, 6 };
```

you can simply do:

```
long num = Long.parseLong(Arrays.stream(arr)
                                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                                .collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

which outputs

> 78379056

---

Explanation:

1. In the `mapToObj(...)` we convert each element from an `int` to
   a `String` using the `valueOf` method.
2. Next, we collect each of these individual Strings into one String by
   means of `Collectors.joining()`
3. Now, we convert *this* String into a long. You can read up more about
   streams from the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-)

*We use long here just in case the number is too big to be contained in an int*.

Comment: That's really a good case to use streams! Can you tell something more about how the `.mapToObject()` function works? Maybe you can say something about the signature `IntFunction<? extends U> mapper`I do not really understand what happens there..

Comment: Sure. Here in the `mapToObj(...)` we convert *each* element from an `int` to a `String` using the valueOf method. Next, we collect each of these individual Strings into *one* String by means of `Collectors.joining(...)`. Now, we convert this String into a `long`. You can read up more about streams from the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-). Edited the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: That's awesome! Big thanks! One question left - Can you furthermore tell me how to read the quoted signature of the `.mapToObj()`-function ? What is *IntFunction*? Does it mean, that a function has to return an IntValue or how is a IntFunction defined? What is *U*? What is the *mapper*?

Comment: It is hard to explain these concepts via comments. 1. `IntFunction` is a functional interface. 2. `U` is used to denote the use of *generics*. 3. `mapper` is the name of the reference of the *generic type U*. I suggest you to try and read up more of these topics to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You can either convert the array into a String and use `Integer.parseInt()` to get this result or you use a simple loop adding up the numbers multiplied by 10 with their position exponent:

```
int r = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    r += result[i] * Math.pow(10, result.length - i - 1);
}
```

I would prefer this solution.

The result for the array `[7, 8, 3, 7, 9, 0, 5, 6]` is `78379056`.

Beside that you should consider using `long` instead of `int` if you have numbers out of the int range (`78379056`).

**Edit:** Here is a solution with `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i : result) {
    builder.append(i);
}
int r = Integer.parseInt(builder.toString());
```

Alternatively you can take a look at *Nicholas K*'s answer.

Comment: I would like to use the `Integer.parseInt()` Option, but the problem is, that if I'm going to execute `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(result.toString()));`

The console prints out:
_`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[I@7852e922"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at dAbgabe.Addition.main(Addition.java:47)`_

Comment: @Twixx you can not use `Array.toString()` you have to generate the String yourself. I added it to my answer. Alternatively look at _Nicholas K_'s Answer he used is using a Stream and a long result.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, you could multiply each number by a power of 10 and add them together. For example this code will return "1234".

```java
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if(array[i] > 9 && array[i] < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only use digits");
    else
        total += array[i] * Math.pow(10, array.length - i - 1);
System.out.println(total);
```

It works in all cases, except cases with number. Make sure you handle the error.

*(be carrefull to Integer.MAX_VALUE)*

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a =  {7, 8, 3, 7, 9, 0, 5, 6};


        int m = 1;
        int r = 0;

        for (int i=a.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            r = a[i] * m + r;
            m = m * 10;
        }

        System.out.println(r);
    }
```

prints:

```
78379056
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to hold the number which is more than int max size as well as you can avoid NumberFormatException.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ary = {2,1,4,7,4,8,3,6,4,7};

        StringBuilder numBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int num:ary) {
            numBuilder.append(num);
        }
        BigInteger maxInt = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        BigInteger finalNum = new BigInteger(numBuilder.toString());
        if(finalNum.compareTo(maxInt)>0) {
            //number is more the max size
            System.out.println("number is more than int max size");
        }else {
            int result = finalNum.intValueExact();
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }
```